# TableView popover is not dismissed [self dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad

I have a popover that displays a tableview with several cells. When a cell is touched, it calls this code:

```
(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSLog(@"Cell check %@", [totalArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]);
    [self dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
}
```

I know this method is called because the NSLOG displays text like it should. The problem is that the popover is not dismissed. I thought that

```
[self dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
```

should dismiss the popover?
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: If this is a delegate method for the tableview inside the popover, it won't work because this tableview doesn't have a popover. The view that has the popover is the view that was on the screen before the popover appeared.

Answer (score 5):

You need to call `dismissPopoverAnimated:` on your popover, not on your view or view controller.
Try to call `[myPopover dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];`

Answer (score 0):

In order to programmatically dismiss a popover, you need to set a delegate because the view that segued to the popover is the one that has to do the dismiss. Check this: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewControllerCatalog/Chapters/Popovers.html